# Microsoft Access cannot load the macro or callback function 'OnRibbonLoad'

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, callback

I set up a custom ribbon in a Microsoft Access DB that is shared over a network. The OnRibbonLoad functions when one user logs in, however, it does not work when another user logs in even from the same computer.

I changed security permissions within the database for the second user to match the first but beyond that, I don't even know where to start.

VBA

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public globalRibbon As IRibbonUI


Public Sub onRibbonLoad(ByVal ribbon As IRibbonUI)
   Set globalRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Public Sub GetImageCallBack(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef image)
    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\DbImages\"

    Select Case control.ID
          Case "appIcon"
              Set image = LoadPicture(strPath & "test4.bmp")
    End Select
End Sub

Public Sub GetUserNameRibbon(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Label)
      Label = "User: " & Environ("Username")
End Sub
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
onLoad="OnRibbonLoad">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="Home" label="Home">
       <group id ="Application" label="Application">
         <button id="AppIcon" getImage="GetImageCallBack" size="large"/>
         <labelControl id="UserID" getLabel="GetUserNameRibbon"/>
       </group>
        <group id="Group1" label="Control">
          <button id="Primary" label="Primary" imageMso="BlogHomePage"
          tag="Primary" onAction="ribOpenForm" getEnabled="ControlEnabled"
          size="large" supertip="Open the Main Menu"/>
        </group>       

      </tab>

    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
```

Comment: Database should be split and each user run their own copy of frontend.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Does this mean that I have to rebuild the database from scratch, as all the tables are in that same Database and they are all linked to forms and queries?

Comment: Don't have to rebuild from scratch. Use the split wizard on Database tab or do it manually. Make a copy and rename it. Delete everything but tables from one, delete tables from the other. Set links in frontend to tables in backend. Distribute frontend to users.

Comment: Same issue after splitting the database

Comment: Was afraid of that but splitting still recommended approach for multi-user db. You are using CurrentProject.Path. If every user runs their own copy opened from their local work station, then the Path will be different for each. However, would think the path would work for all users for non-split version. Try a literal path string instead and see what happens. I would use UNC path: `\\servername\path\test4.bmp`

Comment: the issue is that it is not running the OnRibbonLoad or the GetImageCallback or the GetUserNameRibbon Sub. it did not even have a chance to get to the CurrentProject.Path

Comment: It works for one user only? Sorry, never had this issue.